# x-editable drop down from remote not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, x-editable

I am using X-editable bootstrap version 2

I am using codeigniter . But the text area and text box is working fine for me but drop down is not working .

in my view

```
  

 < a href="#" id="contract" data-type="select" data-pk="1"   data-source="<?php echo base_url('property/contract_get_update')?>" data-title="Select Contract type" class="" >contract data </a>




$( document ).ready(function() {


    $('#contract').editable();

});
```

in my controller

```
  

public function contract_get_update()
    {


        echo "{'M': 'male', 'F': 'female'}";

    }
```

i just tested with this output not working i tried many tricks but it is not seems to be working.

i want to display details from table name contract how can i get that value as a drop down in x-editable

Answer (score 1):

I answered you on gitHub too. The problem is with your json format.

Try this:

```
$contract_types = array();
$contract_types[] = array('value' => 'M', 'text' => 'male');
$contract_types[] = array('value' => 'F', 'text' => 'female');

echo json_encode($contract_types);
```

If you are looping through a db query of results try this in your function:

```
foreach($results AS $result){
    $json_response[] = array('value' => $result['id_column'], 'text' => $result['your_column']);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **custom class** with `text` and `value` members (case sensitive) to enumerate it as a List of type this class then use it to response after ajax call.